# Snowflake metadata: bytes scanned & scanned bytes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using the Snowflake UI - after a given query has completed - one has access to the History tab in order to access/examine corresponding metadata.

Something confusing occurs when I compare the `Bytes Scanned` field (see via History tab and **Image 1**) to the `Scanned Bytes` (see via clicking query ID hyperlink and **Image 2**)

Why are these different? Do they mean different things?

IMAGE 1

[image]

IMAGE 2

[image]

Comment: The difference is likely related to caching.  WIthout seeing all of the details of the query, it is hard to verify that, but if you go into the query profile, you will likely see that this was all from warehouse cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, this "Scanned Bytes" shows total bytes read from Snowflake **tables**. If you are executing a COPY command, it's normal that you see zero bytes (*I also see it shows 0 when querying secure views*).